# siunitx format definition does not take effect

Tags: siunitx, multirow

could someone please me a give me a hint on that? I use the package to align the numbers in the columns of a table. However, it seems that the table format definition does not take effect. For example in row D the minus and the less-than sign seem to break it. Any ideas on how to properly align this?

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{a table.}  
\label{table:x}
\begin{scriptsize}
    \begin{tabular}
        {
            l
            l
            S[table-format = 2.2]
            S[table-format = 2.2]
            S[table-format = -1.2]
            S[table-format = 2]
            S[table-format = 0.2]
        }
        \toprule
        Dim                 &       Cond        & {\emph{M} (secs)}     & {\emph{SD}}           & {\emph{t}}                & {\emph{df}}                   & {\emph{p}}            \\          
        \midrule                
        \multirow{2}{*}{A}  &       B           & 49.50                 & 16.37                 & \multirow{2}{*}{0.03}     & \multirow{2}{*}{15}           & \multirow{2}{*}{.97}  \\
                            &       E           & 49.37                 & 14.89                 &                           &                               &                       \\  

        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{B}  &       B           & 30.37                 & 10.85                 & \multirow{2}{*}{2.88}     & \multirow{2}{*}{15}           & \multirow{2}{*}{.01}  \\
                            &       E           & 24.18                 & 8.78                  &                           &                               &                       \\     

        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{C}  &       B           & 9.12                  & 5.30                  & \multirow{2}{*}{2.38}     & \multirow{2}{*}{15}           & \multirow{2}{*}{.03}  \\
                            &       E           & 5.56                  & 3.36                  &                           &                               &                       \\                                              
        \midrule                                            
        \multirow{2}{*}{D}  &       B           & 0.18                  & 0.54                  & \multirow{2}{*}{-8.90}    & \multirow{2}{*}{15}           & \multirow{2}{*}{{<}.01} \\                    
                            &       E           & 11.50                 & 5.13                  &                           &                               &                       \\     

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please change this into a full minimal example, that others can just copy and test as it is. That makes it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: your table can't works as it is. you need to enclose `multirow`s in curly braces and with this you lost `S` columns properties (contents in them are centered). you should consider to reformat your table (change column type or omit `multirow` cells.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a comment to the answer by @Zarko and how I'd use `\tablenum` here. I use three different macros here as not to add formatting directly into the columns. Notice how the alignment is different in each of the last three columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
% placing these macros here as they are likely to jsut be used for this particular table
\newcommand\mrtnumA[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format=-1.2]{#1}}}
\newcommand\mrtnumB[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format=2.0]{#1}}}
\newcommand\mrtnumC[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format=<1.2]{#1}}}
\centering
\caption{a table.}
\label{table:x}
%\scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}
        {
         *{2}{c}
         *{2}{S[table-format = 2.2]}
         *{3}{c}
        }
        \toprule
Dim                & Cond & {\emph{M} (secs)} & {\emph{SD}} & $t$             & $df$         & $p$             \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & B    & 49.50             & 16.37       & \mrtnumA{0.03}  & \mrtnumB{15} & \mrtnumC{.97}   \\
                   & E    & 49.37             & 14.89       &                 &              &                 \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{B} & B    & 30.37             & 10.85       & \mrtnumA{2.88}  & \mrtnumB{15} & \mrtnumC{.01}   \\
                   & E    & 24.18             & 8.78        &                 &              &                 \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{C} & B    & 9.12              & 5.30        & \mrtnumA{2.38}  & \mrtnumB{15} & \mrtnumC{.03}   \\ 
                   & E    & 5.56              & 3.36        &                 &              &                 \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{D} & B    & 0.18              & 0.54        & \mrtnumA{-8.90} & \mrtnumB{15} & \mrtnumC{< .01} \\
                   & E    & 11.50             & 5.13        &                 &              &                 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zarko not sure if pinging in the body works, so I'll ping here as well.

Comment: meanwhile i ask new question about this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404017/options-in-tablenum). it seems that you solve my problem of using options. i need more time to see all differences. thank you!

Comment: Thank you guys, you really helped me a lot! It now works as expected with the solution by @Zarko and the refinement by daleif  And sorry for not providing the *full* minimal example.

Answer (score 2):

- you not provide complete small document, therefore preamble and document class of your document is unknown. consequently final looks of table's caption is left to you.
- table is you show in question is not possible to compile (see my comment above)
- from possible solutions below is case with redesign column types

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\newcommand\mcm[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{$}c<{$}}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{a table.}
\label{table:x}
%\scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}
        {
         *{2}{c}
         *{2}{S[table-format = 2.2]}
         *{3}{r}
        }
        \toprule
Dim & Cond  & {\emph{M} (secs)}
                    & {\emph{SD}}
                            & \mcm{t}   & \mcm{df}  & \mcm{p}           \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{A}
    & B     & 49.50 & 16.37 & \multirow{2}{*}{0.03}
                                        & \multirow{2}{*}{15}
                                                    &  \multirow{2}{*}{.97}
                                            \\
    & E     & 49.37 & 14.89 &       &       &                           \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{B}
    & B     & 30.37 & 10.85 & \multirow{2}{*}{2.88}
                                    & \multirow{2}{*}{15}
                                            & \multirow{2}{*}{.01}      \\
    & E     & 24.18 & 8.78  &       &       &                           \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{C}
    & B     & 9.12  & 5.30  & \multirow{2}{*}{2.38}
                                    & \multirow{2}{*}{15}
                                            & \multirow{2}{*}{.03}      \\
    & E     & 5.56  & 3.36  &       &       &                           \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{D}
    & B     & 0.18  & 0.54  & \multirow{2}{*}{$-8.90$}
                                    & \multirow{2}{*}{15}
                                            & \multirow{2}{*}{$< .01$}  \\
    & E     & 11.50 & 5.13  &       &       &                           \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**

consider [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) comment below, your table can be formatted as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\newcommand\mrtnum[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{a table.}
\label{table:x}
%\scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}
        {
         *{2}{c}
         *{2}{S[table-format = 2.2]}
         *{3}{c}
        }
        \toprule
Dim & Cond  & {\emph{M} (secs)}
                    & {\emph{SD}}
                            & $t$   & $df$  & $p$           \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{A}
    & B     & 49.50 & 16.37 & \mrtnum{0.03}
                                    & \mrtnum{15}
                                            &  \mrtnum{.97} \\
    & E     & 49.37 & 14.89 &       &       &               \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{B}
    & B     & 30.37 & 10.85 & \mrtnum{2.88}
                                    & \mrtnum{15}
                                            & \mrtnum{.01}  \\
    & E     & 24.18 & 8.78  &       &       &               \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{C}
    & B     & 9.12  & 5.30  & \mrtnum{2.38}
                                    & \mrtnum{15}
                                            & \mrtnum{.03}  \\
    & E     & 5.56  & 3.36  &       &       &               \\
        \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{D}
    & B     & 0.18  & 0.54  & \mrtnum{-8.90}
                                    & \mrtnum{15}
                                            & \mrtnum{< .01} \\
    & E     & 11.50 & 5.13  &       &       &               \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think we can still apply siunitx stuff to col 5, you can use the `\numcell` or what ever it is called. That would be usable for the last two cols as well

Comment: @daleif, i don't know if it is possible and how to do this (with `siunitx` facility) . i'm very interested to learn this.

Comment: I'll see if I can make an example tomorrow (writing on a tablet at present). The macro basically does what S does for a column, but just for a cell. Very useful if you have a column with an overall alignment and a few others that can be aligned separately.

Comment: Looked it up in the manual, p 15, it is called `\tablenum`

Comment: @daleif, i will look in manula (i just upgrade my miktex installation which has now recent `siunitx` :-), so i'm currius, what is new and for `\tablenum`.)

Comment: It has been in siunitx for several years, just probably not mentioned that often in answers

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be using `\multirow` that adds nothing to the understanding of the table: differences are computed *after* the data has been read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{a table.}
\label{table:x}
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  l
  S[table-format =  2.2]
  S[table-format =  2.2]
  S[table-format = -1.2]
  S[table-format =  2.0]
  S[table-format =  1.2,table-comparator=true]
}
\toprule
Dim & Cond  & {$M$ (\si{\sec})} & {$\mathit{SD}$} & {$t$} & {$df$} & {$p$} \\
\midrule
A & B & 49.50 & 16.37 \\
  & E & 49.37 & 14.89 &  0.03 & 15 &  0.97 \\
\addlinespace
B & B & 30.37 & 10.85 \\
  & E & 24.18 &  8.78 &  2.88 & 15 &  0.01 \\
\addlinespace
C & B &  9.12 &  5.30 \\
  & E &  5.56 &  3.36 &  2.38 & 15 &  0.03 \\
\addlinespace
D & B &  0.18 &  0.54 \\
  & E & 11.50 & 5.13  & -8.90 & 15 & <0.01 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]