# Options in \tablenum

Tags: siunitx

Recently I found `\tablenum` very useful in table design ... but in this I'm faced with problems how to use its options known from the `S` column :-(

Please consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num{< 10}

    \begin{table}
This works, but numbers aren't aligned:

\begin{tabular}{S[input-comparators,
                  table-space-text-pre=<,
                  table-format = 1.2]
                c}
        \hline
  1.23  &   \tablenum{  1.23}                       \\
< 1.23  &   \tablenum{< 1.23}                       \\
        \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
This gives error "invalid token '<' in numerical input":

\begin{tabular}{S[input-comparators,
                  table-space-text-pre=<,
                  table-format = 1.2]
                c}
        \hline
  1.23  &   \tablenum{  1.23}                       \\
< 1.23  &   \tablenum[input-comparators,
                      table-space-text-pre=<,
                      table-format = 1.2]{< 1.23}   \\
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If I force compilation, I obtain the following result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Now I also observed that also has a problem with symbol `<` ...

Comment: @Mico, you have right. there was impicite use of OT1 coding. now i correct this, but the main issues still remain ..., however i need to study daleif's answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403880.

Comment: I just uses the `table-format=<1.2`, seemed to work fine

Comment: @daleif, hm, it doesn't work at me. i will return to this problem late afternoon, now i should finished some other tasks

Comment: I've tried both using a macros and direct, `\tablenum[table-format=<1.2]{<.01}` works fine for me on TL2017

Comment: @daleif, yes, this works! please write answer (please, with short explanation, why this work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that `\tablenum` is more-or-less `\num` but with alignment: it is not a macro version of the `S` column. As such, the argument has to be a number. There are various ways to do what you want

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{input-comparators = , table-format = 1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
  \hline
  \hphantom{<}\tablenum{1.23}  \\
  \tablenum[table-space-text-pre=<]{1.23} \\
  <\tablenum{1.23} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Odd, it works fine with `<0.01` in this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404016/3929

Comment: @daleif No: that one leaves `<` alone as a comparator so it _is_ a valid numerical part. Here, we are asked to treat `<` as a non-numerical text element.

Comment: Where is that even asked? I don't see the difference or any reason to place the `<` outside the numerical value.

Comment: @daleif In setting `input-comparators` (equal to nothing) (which removes `<` from being part of a number), plus actively then setting `table-space-text-pre = <`.

Comment: That might have been a left over from Zarkos attempt to solve https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/403880/3929, I have no idea why that was added.

Comment: now i better understand `\tablenum`. in cases with comparators i  will consider *daileif* comment below question ...

Answer (score 4):

`\tablenum` has an optional argument for option settings. However, `input-comparators` does not seem to work, but the important `table-format` does. The following example uses a workaround for the less than symbol:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand*{\mytablenum}{}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\mytablenum}{\tablenum[table-format=1.2]}
\begin{tabular}{S[input-comparators,
                  table-space-text-pre=<,
                  table-format = 1.2]
                c}
\toprule
  1.23  &  \hphantom{<}\mytablenum{1.23}  \\
< 1.23  &             <\mytablenum{1.23}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: At least it does not seem to dies if one uses `table-format=<1.2`

Comment: i observe the same, your workaround is possible solution. it seems that not working options is not planed features or `\tablenum`.